# .NET Library to access the COM Port?

Tags: .net, hardware, serial-port

Is there a library that would allow me to send and receive data on a Serial COM port?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [`System.IO.Ports`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)